# Reverse marquee animation

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm currently working on a infinite marquee text move(animation), but the idea is that when the user scrolls up the animation should flow on the opposite direction.  I have used animation direction reverse but when its "reverted" it doesn't start from the exact position where the user scrolled, generating a not desirable effect. Its important that the text starts at the exact position where it was to flow to the opposite direction.

Someone with any hints?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const textDiv = document.querySelector(".marqueeStyle");
  let lastScrollPos = window.scrollY;

  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    const scrollDirection = scrollPosition > lastScrollPos ? "down" : "up";

    if (scrollDirection === "down") {
      textDiv.classList.remove("scroll-up");
    } else {
      textDiv.classList.add("scroll-up");
    }

    lastScrollPos = scrollPosition;
  });
});
```

```css
.m-scroll {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #d34444;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  &__title {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    &>div {
      display: flex;
      animation: scrollText 33s infinite linear;
      &.scroll-up {
        animation: scrollTextReverse 33s infinite linear;
      }
    }
    h1 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 80px;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      transition: all 2s ease;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes scrollText {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes scrollTextReverse {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marqueeStyle m-scroll"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam congue, tortor nec ornare hendrerit, purus sem aliquet dolor, at ullamcorper metus tellus et tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget porttitor eros. Proin volutpat efficitur risus, sit amet consectetur massa posuere ut. Curabitur tristique, erat vel efficitur congue, mauris nisi consectetur nunc, non hendrerit felis quam ac lacus. Nulla ultricies purus eget nisl commodo, vitae euismod diam pulvinar. Integer eget ante eget urna rutrum faucibus. Aliquam felis est, viverra at tristique sed, imperdiet in ante. Nam vitae augue id dui porttitor condimentum. Donec a ligula quis nibh sodales ultrices. Aenean bibendum ante eu urna mattis, id pulvinar velit efficitur. Vestibulum consectetur, erat in euismod tincidunt, tortor lectus auctor mi, ut molestie felis ex nec erat. Aliquam faucibus neque vel massa tristique, eu bibendum metus hendrerit. Quisque pellentesque fermentum sapien, id convallis purus. Aliquam bibendum ex ut eros eleifend pretium.</p>

<p>Aliquam tristique velit sed efficitur sollicitudin. Ut suscipit at turpis et accumsan. Vivamus malesuada sodales accumsan. In nunc tortor, semper nec consectetur eget, dictum non leo. Quisque condimentum feugiat tincidunt. Vivamus ullamcorper leo sed commodo sollicitudin. Donec malesuada, velit et vestibulum laoreet, leo enim placerat orci, quis finibus erat magna id nunc. In imperdiet vitae massa sit amet accumsan. Quisque eget leo non risus cursus molestie id ac nulla. Aliquam feugiat risus non tellus molestie, ut porttitor lectus feugiat. Nunc eu lectus nulla.</p>

<p>Vestibulum lobortis, lorem volutpat varius elementum, urna lectus pretium augue, nec sollicitudin sapien purus ut nibh. Quisque id nisl interdum, ornare est at, tristique risus. Mauris et sollicitudin nisi. Quisque ullamcorper ac tellus vel molestie. Curabitur molestie metus arcu, iaculis commodo nisl pulvinar sed. Ut efficitur sem et mollis tincidunt. Phasellus dictum porttitor risus, nec mollis enim porta ac. Cras eu ligula semper metus venenatis cursus.</p>

<p>Suspendisse leo neque, rhoncus sit amet neque quis, elementum sollicitudin lectus. Sed condimentum nunc ut suscipit scelerisque. Quisque hendrerit, nibh aliquam consequat pretium, nulla ligula luctus nunc, ut tempus turpis turpis at tellus. Nullam malesuada massa dictum, iaculis eros eget, cursus nisl. Ut dignissim lectus at massa condimentum vestibulum. Nulla quis pretium tellus. Nulla facilisis ex et lectus consectetur, non fringilla metus efficitur.</p>

<p>Etiam sollicitudin dui eu justo viverra egestas. Sed sed metus fermentum, dapibus nisi sed, elementum lacus. Quisque accumsan sed lorem quis mattis. Phasellus lacinia mauris at convallis aliquet. Praesent sagittis, nunc non bibendum molestie, turpis eros efficitur lectus, sed maximus dolor tortor at dolor. Donec nisi nisl, vulputate at sodales consequat, tempor vel arcu. Phasellus eu odio magna. Phasellus massa eros, ultrices ut libero eu, auctor maximus quam. Morbi eget est vel lorem tempus venenatis at in ex. Quisque iaculis justo mauris. Etiam dignissim gravida quam. Sed laoreet luctus laoreet. Morbi consectetur ultrices condimentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam nec dolor ac turpis suscipit pretium id nec magna. Cras consequat magna ut magna mollis ultrices.</div>
```

Comment: I tried to make you a snippet. Please change the HTML to make a [mcve]